# Translate Javascript to Google Appscript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, google-apps-script

I would like to use Javascript code in my Google Appscript. Kindly help. Code is as follows:
I have saved Stylesheet.html file seperately. Kindly let me know how I can call the functions in html file.

```js
<script>
  //google.script.run.updateColors();
  
  
  document.querySelectorAll("input[type='number'], input[type='range']").forEach(doStuff);
  
  function doStuff(){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( {
    this.addEventListener("input", function() {
    if (this.type === "range") {
      this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value;
    } else if (this.type === "number") {
      this.previousElementSibling.value = this.value;
    }

  }
    }).updateColors();


  }

  

  
  function updateColors() {
 
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler({ 
     const colorFront = [ 
    document.querySelector("#color-1-r").value,
    document.querySelector("#color-1-g").value,
    document.querySelector("#color-1-b").value
  ];
  const colorBack = [
    document.querySelector("#color-2-r").value,
    document.querySelector("#color-2-g").value,
    document.querySelector("#color-2-b").value
  ];
  } ).updateDemoColors(colorFront, colorBack).updateBoxesColors(colorFront, colorBack).updateHex(colorFront,colorBack);
  
  }

  function updateHex(colorFront, colorBack) {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(  {
  const colorFrontHex = colorFront.map(function(el) { return Number(el).toString(16).padStart(2, "0").toUpperCase(); });
  const colorBackHex = colorBack.map(function(el) { return Number(el).toString(16).padStart(2, "0").toUpperCase(); });
  document.querySelector("#color-1-hex").value = `#${colorFrontHex.join('')}`;
  document.querySelector("#color-2-hex").value = `#${colorBackHex.join('')}`
  }); 
    
  }

  function updateBoxesColors(colorFront, colorBack) {

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(ratio => {
    const ratio = contrast(colorFront, colorBack);
    document.querySelector("#aa-normal").className  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : "fail";
    document.querySelector("#aa-large").className   = ratio < 0.33333 ? "" : "fail";
    document.querySelector("#aaa-normal").className = ratio < 0.14285 ? "" : "fail";
    document.querySelector("#aaa-large").className  = ratio < 0.22222 ? "" : "fail";

    const totalWrong = document.querySelectorAll(".fail").length;
    let mouth = document.querySelector("#mouth");
    let smile = document.querySelector("#smile");

    switch(totalWrong) {
      case 0:
        mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,142  134,149  125,149  116,149 109,142 106,132 Z");
        smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,144 C 140,144 143,132 143,132 143,132 125,133 125,133 125,133 106.5,132 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,144 125,144 Z");
        break;
      case 1:
      case 2:
        mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,142  134,146  125,146  116,146 109,142 106,132 Z");
        smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,141 C 140,141 143,132 143,132 143,132 125,133 125,133 125,133 106.5,132 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,141 125,141 Z");
        break;
      case 3: 
        mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,138  140,143  125,143  110,143 109,138 106,132 Z");
      smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,138 C 140,138 143.5,132 143.5,132 143.5,132 125,133 125,133 125,133 106.5,132 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,138 125,138 Z");
        break;
      case 4: 
        mouth.setAttribute("d", "M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,138  134,142  125,142  116,142 109,138 106,132 Z");
        smile.setAttribute("d", "M125,135 C 140,135 143,132 143,132 143,135 125,136 125,136 125,136 106.5,135 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,135 125,135 Z");
        break;
    }


    });

}


function updateDemoColors(colorFront, colorBack) {

  google.run.script.withSuccessHandler({ 
    const demo = document.querySelector("#sample-text");
    demo.style.color = `rgb(${colorFront.toString()})`;
    demo.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${colorBack.toString()})`; 
    });
  
}



document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']").forEach(el.addEventListener("blur", el); 

function el()
{

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler({
let val = this.value;
    let wrongValue = false;
    if (val[0] === "#") val = val.substring(1);
    if (val.length === 3 || val.length === 6) {
      if (val.length === 3) {
        val = `${val[0]}${val[0]}${val[1]}${val[1]}${val[2]}${val[2]}`;
      }
      if (val.match(/[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}/)) {
        const red = parseInt(`${val[0]}${val[1]}`, 16);
        const green = parseInt(`${val[2]}${val[3]}`, 16);
        const blue = parseInt(`${val[4]}${val[5]}`, 16);
        const target = this.dataset.target;
        
        document.getElementById(`number-${target}-r`).value = red;
        document.getElementById(`number-${target}-g`).value = green;
        document.getElementById(`number-${target}-b`).value = blue;
        document.getElementById(`color-${target}-r`).value = red;
        document.getElementById(`color-${target}-g`).value = green;
        document.getElementById(`color-${target}-b`).value = blue;
        
        updateColors();
      } else {
        wrongValue = true;
      }
    } else {
      wrongValue = true;
    }
    
    if (wrongValue){
      const colorFront = [ 
        document.querySelector("#color-1-r").value,
        document.querySelector("#color-1-g").value,
        document.querySelector("#color-1-b").value
      ];
      const colorBack = [
        document.querySelector("#color-2-r").value,
        document.querySelector("#color-2-g").value,
        document.querySelector("#color-2-b").value
      ];
    
      }
}).updateHex(colorFront, colorBack);
  

</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <section id="color-contrast">
  <h1>Google Color Contrast Checker</h1>
  <div class="character">
    <div id="jill">
    <svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-labelledby="title  desc">
    <title id="title">Contrast Checker</title>
    <desc id="desc">Cartoon of a Caucasian woman smiling, and wearing black glasses and a purple shirt with white collar.</desc>
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="scene">
        <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="115"/>
      </clipPath>
      <clipPath id="lips">
        <path d="M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,142  134,146  125,146  116,146 109,142 106,132 Z" />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g stroke="none" stroke-width="0" clip-path="url(#scene)">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="250" height="250" fill="#b0d2e5" />
      <g id="head">
        <path fill="none" stroke="#111111" stroke-width="2" d="M 68,103 83,103.5" />
        <path class="hair" d="M 67,90 67,169 78,164 89,169 100,164 112,169 125,164 138,169 150,164 161,169 172,164 183,169 183,90 Z" />
        <circle cx="125" cy="100" r="55" class="skin" />
        <ellipse cx="102" cy="107" rx="5" ry="5" class="eyes" id="eye-left" />
        <ellipse cx="148" cy="107" rx="5" ry="5" class="eyes" id="eye-right" />
        <rect x="119" y="140" width="12" height="40" class="skin" />
        <path class="line eyebrow" d="M 90,98 C 93,90 103,89 110,94" id="eyebrow-left" />
        <path class="line eyebrow" d="M 160,98 C 157,90 147,89 140,94" id="eyebrow-right"/>
        <path stroke="#111111" stroke-width="4" d="M 68,103 83,102.5" />
        <path stroke="#111111" stroke-width="4" d="M 182,103 167,102.5" />
        <path stroke="#050505" stroke-width="3" fill="none" d="M 119,102 C 123,99 127,99 131,102" />
        <path fill="#050505" d="M 92,97 C 85,97 79,98 80,101 81,104 84,104 85,102" />
        <path fill="#050505" d="M 158,97 C 165,97 171,98 170,101 169,104 166,104 165,102" />
        <path stroke="#050505" stroke-width="3" fill="rgba(240,240,255,0.4)" d="M 119,102 C 118,111 115,119 98,117 85,115 84,108 84,104 84,97 94,96 105,97 112,98 117,98 119,102 Z" />
        <path stroke="#050505" stroke-width="3" fill="rgba(240,240,255,0.4)" d="M 131,102 C 132,111 135,119 152,117 165,115 166,108 166,104 166,97 156,96 145,97 138,98 133,98 131,102 Z" />
        <path class="hair" d="M 60,109 C 59,39 118,40 129,40 139,40 187,43 189,99 135,98 115,67 115,67 115,67 108,90 80,109 86,101 91,92 92,87 85,99 65,108 60,109" />
        <path id="mouth" fill="#d73e3e" d="M 106,132 C 113,127 125,128 125,132 125,128 137,127 144,132 141,142  134,149  125,149  116,149 109,142 106,132 Z" /> 
        <path id="smile" fill="white" d="M125,144 C 140,144 143,132 143,132 143,132 125,133 125,133 125,133 106.5,132 106.5,132 106.5,132 110,144 125,144 Z"  />
      </g>
      <g id="shirt">
        <path fill="#8665c2" d="M 132,170 C 146,170 154,200 154,200 154,200 158,245 158,245 158,245 92,245 92,245 92,245 96,200 96,200 96,200 104,170 118,170 118,170 125,172 125,172 125,172 132,170 132,170 Z"/>
        <path id="arm-left" class="arm" stroke="#8665c2" fill="none" stroke-width="14" d="M 118,178 C 94,179 66,220 65,254" />
        <path id="arm-right" class="arm" stroke="#8665c2" fill="none" stroke-width="14" d="M 132,178 C 156,179 184,220 185,254" />
        <path fill="white" d="M 117,166 C 117,166 125,172 125,172 125,182 115,182 109,170 Z" />
        <path fill="white" d="M 133,166 C 133,166 125,172 125,172 125,182 135,182 141,170 Z" />
        <circle cx="125" cy="188" r="4" fill="#5a487b" />
        <circle cx="125" cy="202" r="4" fill="#5a487b" />
        <circle cx="125" cy="216" r="4" fill="#5a487b" />
        <circle cx="125" cy="230" r="4" fill="#5a487b" />
        <circle cx="125" cy="244" r="4" fill="#5a487b" />
        <path stroke="#daa37f" stroke-width="1" class="skin hand" id="hand-left" d="M 51,270 C 46,263 60,243 63,246 65,247 66,248 61,255 72,243 76,238 79,240 82,243 72,254 69,257 72,254 82,241 86,244 89,247 75,261 73,263 77,258 84,251 86,253 89,256 70,287 59,278" /> 
        <path stroke="#daa37f" stroke-width="1" class="skin hand" id="hand-right" d="M 199,270 C 204,263 190,243 187,246 185,247 184,248 189,255 178,243 174,238 171,240 168,243 178,254 181,257 178,254 168,241 164,244 161,247 175,261 177,263 173,258 166,251 164,253 161,256 180,287 191,278"/> 
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="boxes">
    <div id="aa-large">
      <span>Large Text</span>
      <span>WCAG AA</span>
    </div>
    <div id="aa-normal">
      <span>Normal Text</span>
      <span>WCAG AA</span>
    </div>
    <div id="aaa-large">
      <span>Large Text</span>
      <span>WCAG AAA</span>
    </div>
    <div id="aaa-normal">
      <span>Normal Text</span>
      <span>WCAG AAA</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="sample">
    <div contenteditable id="sample-text" style="color:rgb(0,0,0);background:rgb(255,255,255)">
      Click to change demo text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ratioContainer" class="pass">
        <span>
            Contrast Ratio
            <span id="ratio" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="false"><b>4.76</b>:1</span>
        </span>
        
    </div>

  <div id="bars">
    <div>
      
      <input id="color-1-hex" data-target="1" type="text" value="#000000" maxlength="7" />
      <h2>Foreground</h2>
      <div>
        <label for="color-1-r" class="red">R</label> 
        <input id="color-1-r" type="range" min="0" max="255" value="0" />
        <input id="number-1-r" type="number" min="0" max="255" value="0" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="color-1-g" class="green">G</label> 
        <input id="color-1-g" type="range" min="0" max="255" value="0" />
        <input id="number-1-g" type="number" min="0" max="255" value="0" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="color-1-b" class="blue">B</label> 
        <input id="color-1-b" type="range" min="0" max="255" value="0" />
        <input id="number-1-b" type="number" min="0" max="255" value="0" />
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="color-2-hex" data-target="2" type="text" value="#FFFFFF" maxlength="7" />
      <h2>Background</h2>
      <div>
        <label for="color-2-r" class="red">R</label> 
        <input id="color-2-r" type="range" min="0" max="255" value="255" />
        <input id="number-2-r" type="number" min="0" max="255" value="255" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="color-2-g" class="green">G</label> 
        <input id="color-2-g" type="range" min="0" max="255" value="255" />
        <input id="number-2-g" type="number"min="0" max="255" value="255" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="color-2-b" class="blue">B</label> 
        <input id="color-2-b" type="range" min="0" max="255" value="255" />
        <input id="number-2-b" type="number" min="0" max="255" value="255" />
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>



  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to use Javascript code in my Google Appscript. Kindly help. Code is as follows:
I have saved Stylesheet.html file seperately. Kindly let me know how I can call the functions in html file.

So, I would appreciate if anyone can suggest me that how can this be modified to google appscript.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

In order to call an Apps Script function in the HTML file, you will have to use the `google.script.run` client-side JavaScript API call.

Assuming that you want to call the `contrast` function from *Code.gs*, you will have to add this in your *Page.html* file:

```
<script>
    google.script.run.contrast();
</script>
```

#### Explanation

However, please bear in mind that the client side (aka the *Code.gs* in your situation) will *have to* use Apps Script compliant methods - meaning, you **cannot** call DOM elements, such as `document` for instance.

If you want to keep on using the functions you have, you will have to integrate them in your HTML file and keep the Apps Script code to strictly call the `doGet` function.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html).

Comment: Thanks @ale13 I am editing my ques. Please let me know where is the problem now

Comment: @tanaike Could you please answer if you know its solution that where I am going wrong in functions?