# Is there a way to get RGB value from a live camera feed in reactJs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, camera

I was wondering in ReactJS/ReactApp if it is possible to capture the RGB color from Center Pixel of a Live Camera Feed displayed on a website (honestly any pixel can do fine or we could average out the entire video frame - whatever simpler)?

All this camera does is displays a feed (of the devices rear camera) which is designed by the website (no need for pictures or video taken).

```js
function Camera() {
    const videoRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        getVideo();
    }, [videoRef]);

    const getVideo = () => {
        navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({ video: {facingMode: 'environment', width: 600 , height: 400}})
            .then(stream => {
                let video = videoRef.current;
                video.srcObject = stream;
                video.play();
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error("error:", err);
            });
    };

        return (
            <div>
                <video ref={videoRef} />
            </div>
        )
}

export default Camera;
```

As well, this camera Implementation was Modified from: https://itnext.io/accessing-the-webcam-with-javascript-and-react-33cbe92f49cb

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `videoRef` and do something like this.

```
  const {video} = videoRef.current;
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas'); 
  canvas.width = 600;
  canvas.height = 400;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 600, 400);
  const rgbaData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,600,400).data;
```

The above code grabs the video stream from your videoRef then you create a 2d canvas and draw your stream onto it.

From there you just do `getImage` fill out the parameters on what part of the image you want the pixels from and then `.data` is a single dimensional array of rgba values containing all the pixels in the image.

(note: this also doesn't require drawing the canvas onto the screen)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData

And then to get the average pixel color you can look at this post:

[Get average color of image via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541481/get-average-color-of-image-via-javascript)

But if you're looking to find pixel brightness you can use this

[Formula to determine perceived brightness of RGB color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-perceived-brightness-of-rgb-color/13558570#13558570)

And lastly for contrast of pixels

[How to programmatically calculate the contrast ratio between two colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733288/how-to-programmatically-calculate-the-contrast-ratio-between-two-colors)

Note you will also probably want to chunk together the single dimensional array into `[[rgba],[rgba]]` chunks rather than the `[r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a]` structure the array already comes in.

```
const chunk = (a, n) => [...Array(Math.ceil(a.length / n))].map((_, i) => a.slice(n * i, n + n * i));
```

`a - being the array`

`n - being the chunk size (in this case 4 since rgba)`